# Recursive Data Jquery Object

Tags: jquery, recursion

I'm trying to create Recursive Data in Jquery Object. I have almost done much opening form inside the popup getting data and storing in jquery object but facing an issue in sub question inside option its duplicating the main question. its adding option inside the question properly but i'm adding sub question with same function just by getting parent ID but its adding sub question two time duplicate the main question

```
var ParentIndex = 0;
var QuestionIndex = 0;
var OptionIndex = 0;
var Question = [];
var Model = null;

$(function(){
    // Create Question
    var ParentIDX = parseInt($('[data-type=OQ]').attr('data-parent'));
    ParentIDX = isNaN(ParentIDX) ? 0 : ParentIDX;

    // Create Question
    CreateQuestion('[data-type=OQ]',ParentIDX);

    // Remove Question
    $('body').on('click','a[data-type=RQ]',function(){
        var Parent = parseInt($(this).attr('data-parent'));
        delete Question[Index];
        $('[data-type=QRow][data-index='+Index+']').remove();
    });
    // Remove Options
    // Remove Question
    /*
    $('body').on('click','a[data-type=RO]',function(){
        var Index = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'));
        delete Question[Index];
        $('[data-type=QRow][data-index='+Index+']').remove();
    });
    */

});

function CreateQuestion(Trigger,Parent){
    Model = $(Trigger).avgrund({
     height: 500,
     holderClass: 'custom',
     closeByEscape: true,
     closeByDocument: true,
     showClose: true,
     showCloseText: 'x',
     onBlurContainer: '.container-scroller',
     template: '<form name="AddQuestion"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-12"> <div class="form-group"><label>Title</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Title"/></div></div><div class="col-sm-12"> <div class="form-group"><label>Role</label><select name="Role" class="form-control">'+(Roles)+'</select></div></div><div class="col-sm-6"> <div class="form-group"> <label>Weight</label> <div class="input-group"><input class="form-control" placeholder="Weight" name="Weight" type="text"/><span class="input-group-append"><a class="btn btn-info text-white">%</a></span></div></div></div><div class="col-sm-6"><label>&nbsp;</label><div class="form-check form-check-flat mt-0"><input name="NotNA" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"/> N/A</div> </div><div class="col-sm-12"> <div class="form-group"><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-success col-12" data-type="ADQ" data-index="'+QuestionIndex+'" data-parent="'+Parent+'"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Question </a></div></div></div></form>'
   });

  $('body').on('click','a[data-type=ADQ]',function(){
     var Data = {
         'Question' : $('input[name=Title]').val(),
         'Role' : $('select[name=Role]').val(),
         'Weight' : $('input[name=Weight]').val(),
         'NotNa' : $('input[name=NotNA]').prop("checked") ? 1 : 0,
         'Options' : [],
         'Parent' : $(this).attr('data-parent')
     }
     // Pushing Data to Object
     Question.push(Data);
     // Increasing Index
     QuestionIndex++;
     // Appending Question
     if(parseInt(Question[Question.length - 1].Parent) == 0){
         // Finding Entry Index
         var Index = parseInt(Question.length - 1);
         // Defining Title
         var QuestionTitle = Question[Question.length - 1].Question;
         // HTML
         var HTML = '<div class="mb-3" data-type="QRow" data-index="'+Index+'"><div class="card border-success rounded"> <div class="card-header"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-8 pt-1">'+QuestionTitle+'</div><div class="col-sm-4 text-right"> <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info mr-1" data-type="OPO" data-parent="'+Index+'"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Option</a><a  href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger" data-type="RQ" data-index="'+Index+'"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></div></div></div><div class="card-body bg-light" data-type="OUNQ" data-parent="'+Index+'"></div></div></div>'
         // Append Question
        $('[data-type=Questions]').append(HTML);
        $('.avgrund-close').click();
        // Create Option
        CreateOption('[data-type=OPO]',Index);
    } else {
        var Index = parseInt(Question.length - 1);
        // Defining Title
        var QuestionTitle = Question[Question.length - 1].Question;
        // HTML
        var HTML = '<div class="mb-3" data-type="QRow" data-index="'+Index+'"><div class="card border-success rounded"> <div class="card-header"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-8 pt-1">'+QuestionTitle+'</div><div class="col-sm-4 text-right"> <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info mr-1" data-type="OPO" data-parent="'+Index+'"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Option</a><a  href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger" data-type="RQ" data-index="'+Index+'"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></div></div></div><div class="card-body bg-light" data-type="OUNQ" data-parent="'+Index+'"></div></div></div>'
        // Append Question
       $('[data-type=QUNO][data-parent='+Parent+']').append(HTML);
       $('.avgrund-close').click();
       // Create Option
       CreateOption('[data-type=OPO]',Index);
   }
  });
}

function CreateOption(Trigger,Parent){

    Model = $(Trigger).avgrund({
     height: 500,
     holderClass: 'custom',
     closeByEscape: true,
     closeByDocument: true,
     showClose: true,
     showCloseText: 'x',
     onBlurContainer: '.container-scroller',
     template: '<form name="AddOption"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="form-group"><label>Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name"></div></div><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="form-group"><label>Type</label><select name="Type" class="form-control"><option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option><option value="radio">Radio</option></select></div></div><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group"><label>Effect</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Effect"></div></div><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="form-group"><label>Point</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Point"></div></div><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="form-check form-check-flat mt-0"><input name="FatalError" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"> FatalError</div></div><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="form-group"><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-success col-12" data-type="ADO" data-index="'+OptionIndex+'" data-parent="'+Parent+'"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Option </a></div></div></div></form>'
   });

   $('body').on('click','a[data-type=ADO]',function(){
        var Data = {
            'Option' : $('input[name=Name]').val(),
            'Type' : $('select[name=Type]').val(),
            'Effect' : $('input[name=Effect]').val(),
            'Point' : $('input[name=Point]').val(),
            'FatalError' : $('input[name=FatalError]').prop("checked") ? 1 : 0,
            'Parent' : $(this).attr('data-parent')
        }

        // Pushing Data to Object
        var Options = Question[Parent].Options;
        Options.push(Data);
        // Increasing Index
        OptionIndex++;
        // Appending Option
        var Index = parseInt(Options.length - 1);
        var Name = Options[Index].Option;
        // Creating Option HTML
        var HTML = '<div class="mb-3" data-type="ORow" data-index="'+Index+'"> <div class="card border-success rounded"> <div class="card-header"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-8 pt-1">'+Name+'</div> <div class="col-sm-4 text-right"> <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-success mr-1" data-type="OQ" data-parent="'+Index+'"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Question</a><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger" data-type="RO" data-index="'+Index+'" data-parent="'+Parent+'"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></div> </div> </div> <div class="card-body bg-light" data-type="QUNO" data-parent="'+Index+'"></div> </div></div>'
        // Append Question
       $('[data-type=OUNQ][data-parent='+Parent+']').append(HTML);
       $('.avgrund-close').click();

       // Create Question
       CreateQuestion('[data-type=OQ]',Parent);
   });
}
```

Comment: What's `.avgrund()`, a plugin?

Comment: yes its third party plugin